# How to improve latency in a multi-threaded application?

Tags: c++, linux

I am having a rather peculiar problem and I don't really know where to start looking for what is going on.

I have a heavily multi-threaded code [single application, 20+ threads] running. I send a sleep signal to the code and seconds later cont signal to wake up. When the application does wake up, if I send some message to one of the threads from an external app the latency is high and the response does not it make it within my expected timeout. This is about 10% of the times, remaining 90% code is running as it should.

For what it's worth this is C++ on RHEL6 and a lot of communication is happening by either TCP or multi-cast between applications. Maybe I need to do kernel tuning, not sure.

Any ideas where I should start looking?

Comment: Have you profiled it?

Comment: usually heavily multithreaded applications come with lots of locks. and context switches are not for free. and especially if you have semaphores and you see unwanted delays: it might be that the semaphore doesn't strictly order for performance reasons.

Comment: How do I profile an app thats waking up from sleep?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you send a `STOP` or `TSTP` signal (there is no "sleep" signal in [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)) using [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html).

Perhaps instead of sending signals you could use some simple textual protocol on a "controlling" fifo or socket (or maybe use [dbus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/). Then you'll just add that control socket or file descriptor to the set of fds managed by your event loop. (e.g. thru [poll(2)](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/) etc...). This is more orthogonal with a communicating application.

But you really should show us your code to get more precise hints.

Comment: I do send STOP and wake with SIGCONT. Not familiar with dbus.